# Javascript error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can someone help...I am testing my asp.net application in chrome. On successful login I am receiving this error in JavaScript Console.

Code snippet where error occurs:

```
function ChangeToStaticImage() 
{   
//Error occurs after this line
    if ( window.Form1 && window.Form1.document.getElementById('div_Running') )
    {
        document.getElementById('div_Running').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('div_Running').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Actual java script error:

> Uncaught Type Error: 
>   Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you checking for something as strange as `window.Form1.document` when you're using just `document.getElementById` inside the condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Well `window.Form1.document` is not an object, such property does not exists. Try `document.getElementById` instead. Form objects does not contain document object. The document is one and only in the loaded page (or iframe). The method `getElementById` belongs to the `document` object. So your code should look like:

```
function ChangeToStaticImage() 
{
     //Error occurs after this line
     if ( document.getElementById('div_Running') )
     {
         document.getElementById('div_Running').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('div_Running').style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
 }
```

Comment: So..this is a problem with Chrome ?...since the code works for IE

Comment: This is the valid way through all browsers. There might be no error in IE, but it does not mean it is correct or if it will work correctly with Form1.document.

Comment: Should it be the same case for top.document.forms[0].document.getElementById('div_Running')

Comment: The document can be accessed directly if no frames or iframes are present. Forms do not have document - there is **no form.document**, no matter how you call it *Form1.document* or *forms[0].document*, since Form1 and forms[0] refer the same object possibly in your code. This is valid for multiple forms too. They have elements, like: `forms[0].elements`, which are input components. All you need is `document.getElementById` - the idea is that on a single page all your elements should have unique id (id=".."), you cannot have two or more elements with the same ID. And the page is the document.

Comment: So the document have forms, but the forms do not have document.

Comment: It is possible in IE a form to contain reference to its parent document, but this would be IE specific.